# Issues debugging Errai app in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, errai

When degugging an Errai application in Eclipse, I get the following error.

```
   [WARN] failed com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload@1575d48{/,/home/matthew/git/PressGangCCMSUI/src/main/webapp}: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/context/FacesContext
   [WARN] failed RequestLogHandler@ad4bb0: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/context/FacesContext
   [WARN] Error starting handlers
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/context/FacesContext
```

Does anyone know how to fix this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was because Eclipse was using a local Maven project as a dependency instead of the JAR file in the local repo cache. Once I close the project that my Errai app was dependant on, Eclipse reverted back to using the JAR in the local repo cache, and I could launch the debugger again.